# Nginx Redirect Loop

Tags: php, nginx

Below is my configuration for nginx.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$query_string;

    # Remove trailing slash
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

    rewrite /authors/(.*) /authors/search.php?author=$1;
}
```

The problem I am having is that when I go to www.mywebsite.com/authors this causes an infinite redirect. What I want is for www.mywebsite.com/authors to load www.mywebsite/authors/index.php and www.mywebsite.com/authors/EVERYOTHERSTRING to go to the last rewrite. How can I achieve this with rewrites?

Edit: And still have the trailing slashes removed.

Comment: `/authors/search.php?author=$1;` matches `/authors/(.*)`. So it rewrites itself infinitely

Comment: No, the problem isn't that alone. I changed `/authors/search.php?author=$1;` to `/authorsTEMP/search.php?author=$1;` and the error still occurred. It has something to do with the trailing slash line because the redirect error stops when I remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing these rewrite rules ...

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent; 
rewrite /authors/(.*) /authors/search.php?author=$1;
```

to ...

```
rewrite ^/authors/(.*) /authors/search.php?author=$1 last;
rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
```